# Why is function not being called?

Tags: javascript, tree

I have tried to code a tree that has a structure like that of a file tree. I am trying to run a piece of code (tree.prototype.traversalBF) in the 'tree.prototype.add' code.

issue is here:

```
    Tree.prototype.traversalBF = function(node, pathPart) {
        //determines number of children of the given node
        console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        var length = node.children.length;
        var i = 0;
        var found = false;
        console.log(node);
        //cycles through until there is a match
        while( found != true && i < length){
            if(node.children[i] == pathPart){
                found = true;
                //when there is a match it returns the node
                return node.children[i];
            } else if( i = length) {
                var nodeFile = new Node(pathPart);
                //adds the file name onto the the node
                node.children.push(nodeFile);
                //sets the node parent to the currentNode
                nodeFile.parent = node;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    Tree.prototype.add = function(path){
    var pathSplit = path.split('/');
    //gets the length of the path
    var pathLength = pathSplit.length;
    console.log(pathLength);
    //this compares the path to the nodes/directories
    let compare = (currentNode, n) => {
        //console.log(n);
        if(n == pathLength -1){
            console.log(pathLength+ "secons");
            console.log(currentNode.data)
            //create a new node with file name as data
            var nodeFile = new Node(pathSplit[n]);
            //adds the file name onto the the node
            currentNode.children.push(nodeFile);
            //sets the node parent to the currentNode
            nodeFile.parent = currentNode;
        }else{
            var newNode = () => this.traversalBF(currentNode, pathSplit[n]);
            console.log(newNode);
            compare(newNode, n+1);
        };

    };
    compare(this._root, 0);
    };
```

the else statment is run but the traversalBF is not run given the console.log('!!!!...!!!') doesn't log.

Comment: if i understand well, `compare` is supposed to be passed a node as first argument, not a function, so maybe `compare(newNode(), n+1);` (with round brackets) is all that you need? (or maybe just remove the `() => `, to straightly get the node instead a creating a function)

Comment: using the brackets worked thanks. However it is saying: 
test.js:31
    var length = node.children.length; "cannot read property 'children' of undefined"